# NASM Segmentation fault

Tags: 64-bit, nasm, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using a 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS VM and I'm trying to write a simple x64 assembly code that will print "Owned!!!".

Because I don't want any 0x00 or 0x0a bytes and I want the code to be position independent (because I'm learning how to write shellcodes), I wrote it this way:

```
;hello4.asm  attempts to make the code position independent

section .text

global _start

_start:
;clear out the registers we are going to need
xor rax, rax
xor rbx, rbx
xor rcx, rcx
xor rdx, rdx

;write(int fd, char *msg, unsigned int len)
mov al, 4
mov bl, 1
;Owned!!! =  4f,77,6e,65,64,21,21,21
;push !,!,!,d
push 0x21212164
;push e,n,w,O 
push 0x656e774f
mov rcx, rsp
mov dl, 8
int 0x80

;exit(int ret)
mov al,1
xor rbx, rbx
int 0x80
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
user@PC:~/Desktop/exploitsclass/hello_shellcode$ nasm -f elf64 hello4.asm
user@PC:~/Desktop/exploitsclass/hello_shellcode$ ld hello4.o -o hello4
user@PC:~/Desktop/exploitsclass/hello_shellcode$ objdump -d hello4 -M intel

hello4:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400080 <_start>:
  400080:   48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
  400083:   48 31 db                xor    rbx,rbx
  400086:   48 31 c9                xor    rcx,rcx
  400089:   48 31 d2                xor    rdx,rdx
  40008c:   b0 04                   mov    al,0x4
  40008e:   b3 01                   mov    bl,0x1
  400090:   68 64 21 21 21          push   0x21212164
  400095:   68 4f 77 6e 65          push   0x656e774f
  40009a:   48 89 e1                mov    rcx,rsp
  40009d:   b2 08                   mov    dl,0x8
  40009f:   cd 80                   int    0x80
  4000a1:   b0 01                   mov    al,0x1
  4000a3:   48 31 db                xor    rbx,rbx
  4000a6:   cd 80                   int    0x80
user@PC:~/Desktop/exploitsclass/hello_shellcode$ ./hello4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I've understood that `int 0x80` is intended for 32-bit programs and I should use `syscall` instead and that `syscall` has different ids for each system call.

The new code is:

```
;hello4.asm  attempts to make the code position independent

section .text

global _start

_start:
;clear out the registers we are going to need
xor rax, rax
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdi, rdi
xor rdx, rdx

;write(int fd, char *msg, unsigned int len)
mov al, 1
add di, 1
;Owned!!! =  4f,77,6e,65,64,21,21,21
;push !,!,!,d
push 0x21212164
;push e,n,w,O 
push 0x656e774f
mov rsi, rsp
mov dl, 8
syscall

;exit(int ret)
mov al, 60
xor rdi, rdi
syscall
```

The output is `Owne%` instead of `Owned!!!` now.
It still needs to be fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using interrupt 0x80 on 64-bit Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503944/using-interrupt-0x80-on-64-bit-linux)

Comment: I've tried to change the `int 0x80` to `syscall` but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @CertainLach I've written the correct code:

```
;hello4.asm  attempts to make the code position independent

section .text

global _start

_start:
;clear out the registers we are going to need
xor rax, rax
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdi, rdi
xor rdx, rdx

;write(int fd, char *msg, unsigned int len)
mov al, 1
add di, 1
;Owned!!! =  4f,77,6e,65,64,21,21,21
mov rsi, 0x21212164656e774f
push rsi
mov rsi, rsp
mov dl, 8
syscall

;exit(int ret)
mov al, 60
xor rdi, rdi
syscall
```

This code contains no null bytes or 0x0a bytes and it's position-independent, as following:

```
user@PC:~/Desktop/exploitsclass/hello_shellcode$ objdump -d hello4 -M intel

hello4:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400080 <_start>:
  400080:   48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
  400083:   48 31 f6                xor    rsi,rsi
  400086:   48 31 ff                xor    rdi,rdi
  400089:   48 31 d2                xor    rdx,rdx
  40008c:   b0 01                   mov    al,0x1
  40008e:   66 83 c7 01             add    di,0x1
  400092:   48 be 4f 77 6e 65 64    movabs rsi,0x21212164656e774f
  400099:   21 21 21 
  40009c:   56                      push   rsi
  40009d:   48 89 e6                mov    rsi,rsp
  4000a0:   b2 08                   mov    dl,0x8
  4000a2:   0f 05                   syscall 
  4000a4:   b0 3c                   mov    al,0x3c
  4000a6:   48 31 ff                xor    rdi,rdi
  4000a9:   0f 05                   syscall
```

This is also a correct way of implementing the solution, which is 1 bytecode less, but with more memory consumption:

```
user@PC:~/Desktop/exploitsclass/hello_shellcode$ cat hello4.asm
;hello4.asm  attempts to make the code position independent

section .text

global _start

_start:
;clear out the registers we are going to need
xor rax, rax
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdi, rdi
xor rdx, rdx

;write(int fd, char *msg, unsigned int len)
mov al, 1
add di, 1
;Owned!!! =  4f,77,6e,65,64,21,21,21
;push !,!,!,d
push 0x21212164
;push e,n,w,O
push 0x656e774f
mov rsi, rsp
mov dl, 16
syscall

;exit(int ret)
mov al, 60
xor rdi, rdi
syscall

user@PC:~/Desktop/exploitsclass/hello_shellcode$ objdump -d hello4 -M intel

hello4:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400080 <_start>:
  400080:   48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
  400083:   48 31 f6                xor    rsi,rsi
  400086:   48 31 ff                xor    rdi,rdi
  400089:   48 31 d2                xor    rdx,rdx
  40008c:   b0 01                   mov    al,0x1
  40008e:   66 83 c7 01             add    di,0x1
  400092:   68 64 21 21 21          push   0x21212164
  400097:   68 4f 77 6e 65          push   0x656e774f
  40009c:   48 89 e6                mov    rsi,rsp
  40009f:   b2 10                   mov    dl,0x10
  4000a1:   0f 05                   syscall 
  4000a3:   b0 3c                   mov    al,0x3c
  4000a5:   48 31 ff                xor    rdi,rdi
  4000a8:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer your comment, you can't just change `int 0x80` to `syscall` to make it work, system call numbers differ, i.e sys_write you have here, have id `4` for `int 0x80`, and id `1` with `syscall`

[Here](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) you can see numbers for `syscall`

And [here](https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) for `int 0x80`

Comment: `mov dl, 8` => `mov dl, 16`

Comment: Because it's a 64-bit address, is there a way to push the entire string to one line? I've tried `push 0x21212164656e774f` but it raised an error

Comment: Probally, % - it is symbol written by your terminal, if output has no newlines at end.
You can try `echo -n "Hello world"` to test it

Comment: I've examined `rsp` using gdb. This is the output:
`(gdb) x/16x $rsp
0x7fffffffdf90: 0x4f 0x77 0x6e 0x65 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x7fffffffdf98: 0x64 0x21 0x21 0x21 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`
Now I just need to make one push that will eliminate all the 0x00 bytes.

Comment: There is no instruction to push x64 bit value to stack, use
```mov rcx, 0x21212164656e774f
push rcx
```
Instead, and then change `mov dx, 16` back to `mov dx, 8`

Comment: Thank you so much! The `%` came from my ohmyzsh shell. When I switched to bash, it disappeared.

Comment: In fact, solution with `mov dl, 16` isn't correct, because it also writes 8 unneeded `\0` chars (You can verify it with `wc --bytes`), i written them because i messed `write` with windows and utf-16 :D