# Cannot print the string to which the stack address points using INT80 in Ubuntu system

Tags: nasm

I can print character in  label that in section .data
But I can't print character use stack address

```
section .data
    break   db  "a"

section .text

global _start
_start:
    mov rax, qword 'a'
    push rax
    ; push 'a' to stack

    mov rax,4
    mov rbx,1

    ; get stack top pointer and mov to rcx register
    mov rcx,rsp
    ; If replace rsp with label <break> that can print newlines character
    ; mov rcx,break

    mov rdx,1
    int 80h

    pop rax

    call quit

quit:
    mov     rbx, 0      
    mov     rax, 1      
    int     80h
    ret
```

```
console>
```

not print anything

If replace rsp with label  that can print newlines

```
; mov rcx, rsp 
mov rcx, break
```

```
console>a#
```

print one character

Makefile

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    nasm -f elf64 test.asm
    ld -s -o test test.o
    ./test

.PHONY: test_debug
test_debug:
    nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g test.asm
    ld -g -o test test.o
    gdb test
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix `int 80h` and 64-bit code. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503944/using-interrupt-0x80-on-64-bit-linux or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code

Comment: @ecm thank you so much for helping me solve a problem that has been puzzling me for a long time